# What is Codecov score and how it is measured?

Tags: php, code-coverage

I am a PHP developer and recently started writing test cases for my codes. I am using Travis CI for continuous integration and I have found another service named `Codecov.io` and integrated them with my code repository.

They are giving me a score of `54%` (https://codecov.io/gh/SumonMSelim/testing-laravel). I want to know what does this score means and how it is measured?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Coverage is used to help developers determine what lines of code were executed by their tests. There are three primary terms used to indicate the results of your tests: hit, partial and miss. The value of `54%` comes from a calculation of `hit / ( hits + partial + miss) = coverage`.

- A hit is a line (aka statement) that is fully executed by your tests.
- A partial is a statement (typically a branch) that is not fully executed. Example `if true:...` will always be a partial hit because the branch was never skipped because `true` is always `true`.
- A miss is a statement that was not executed by tests.

A grade of `54%`, in simple terms, says "Half my code is tested". Use Codecov to investigate methods and statements in your code that are not tested to help guide you on where to write your next test and increase the coverage.

Comment: Is the goal to increase this value, then? Or does it depend on the project?

Comment: Yes. The goal is to increase the coverage therefore increasing your coverage ratio.